# Mount VM filesystem on host

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I'm using Proxmox for virtualization and I need to mount my KVM VM filesystem inside the hypervisor. Is this possible without shutting down my VM? Basically, I need a script that could do following steps:

mount VM filesystem -> tar some files -> unmount filesystem

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using LVM, File storage or iSCSI or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about proxmox, it's a weird hybrid thing, but you could use `qemu-nbd` to achieve what you want. The trick is - you can't know when the guest might want to alter the files that are being `tar`-ed, and if that happens, the backup you're taking is worthless.

Comment: just keep in mind, that the nbd module is probably going to become deprecated at some point, and you're better off using libvirt's libguestfs instead